# Django 1.11 not recognising Foreign Key model assignments

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am having an issue with 2 Foreign Key assignments in my django model. See **models.py** below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class userData(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(User)
    house           = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address         = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    street          = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    state           = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    postcode        = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    country         = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    telephone       = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    subscription    = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    active          = models.IntegerField(default=0)



class area(models.Model):
    area_name       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    longitude       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    latitude        = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class country(models.Model):
    area_name       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    longitude       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    latitude        = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class city(models.Model):
    area_name       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    longitude       = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    latitude        = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class foodType(models.Model):
    food_type_name  = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class restaurant(models.Model):
    restaurant_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    food_type       = models.ForeignKey(foodType)
    area            = models.ForeignKey(area)
    country         = models.ForeignKey(country)
    city            = models.ForeignKey(city)
    date_added      = models.DateField()
    main_image      = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    website         = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    summary         = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    description     = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    featured        = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class restaurantFeature(models.Model):
    feature_name    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    restaurant_id   = models.ForeignKey(restaurant)
```

[Django Foreign Key not working correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovwCh.png)

The image shows the Country and City, not showing correctly, like the FoodType and Area does. Theses show with the + buttons for adding, the mysql database is showing the key next to the fields. I have also tried renaming country and City adding Location after, thinking it could be something with these names.

Appreciate any help with this one.

Comment: Note that in Django, it's recommended to capitalize your model names, e.g. `Country`, `FoodType` and `RestaurantFeature`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having this issue because you need to reference ALL the models inside the `admin.py`. Django admin doesn't know what you're referencing.